# Lock the newly inserted row [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to lock a recently inserted row so that other transaction do will not see it while my current transaction is still going on?

Comment: If you `INSERT` inside a transaction, it will not be visible to any other connections until that transaction issues a `COMMIT`. There's no need to perform any additional locking.

Comment: thanks, yea I just realize that! For all isolation level, it has that behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to. In fact, you can't have the opposite behaviour. There's no way to make your newly inserted row visible until your transaction commits.

Despite the fact that it's not visible to concurrent `SELECT`, it can still affect concurrent `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`s) though. Specifically, if you try to insert the same value into a unique index in two different transactions, one will block until the other commits or rolls back. Then it'll decide if it needs to raise a unique violation error, or if it can continue. So while you cannot directly see uncommitted data, sometimes you can see its side effects.